# Using a class constructor to create object arrays of 2 different types

Tags: java, object, constructor

I'm implementing a database of sorts for a data structures project and i'm having a really hard time wrapping my head around the logic of what I need to do.

I have an abstract superclass, called `Person`, which has two child classes named `Student` and `Instructor`.

Lastly, I have another class called `UniversityPeople` which creates a reference to an array of both `Student` and `Instructor` objects when used by the application. When the constructor for `UniversityPeople` is called, it creates an array of the specified object using size as a parameter. I can't seem to think how to distinguish the two objects in the constructor at creation. My first thought was 2 constructors:

```
Instructor[] instArray;
Student[] stuArray;

public UniversityPeople(int size)
{
    Student[] stuArray = new Student[size];
}
public UniversityPeople(int size)
{
    Instructor[] instArray = new Instructor[size];
}
```

But after thinking about it(and doing some reading) I know I cannot do this. 
My next thought was to use a type of object validation method in the `UniversityPeople` constructor, but i'm having a hard time implementing one.

Basically, the class needs to know when to create an array of `Student` objects and when to create an array of `Instructor` objects with an integer size as an argument.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it. I've been mostly coding in C lately so the return to OOP has felt a little weird after so much time. Thanks!

Comment: Why not create an array of Person?

Comment: You could create static factory methods on `UniversityPeople`, which, unlike constructors, could be distinguished from each other by name.  But I don't understand your requirement very well.  Why would your class have two arrays as members, but only initialize one?

Comment: because its abstract, and if I remember reading correctly, the subclasses would not have access to their methods, only those of the abstract superclass. I could be wrong though?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I guess my thinking was, if the application user did not want to enter instructor data and instead only enter data for students they could, but my approach could be way off.

Comment: Sounds like a use-case for generics. `UniversityGroup<T extends Person>`, which holds an array of `T`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, I'd question the approach - it sounds like this single class is trying to do too many things. But if you really, really want to do it, I'd recommend static factory methods calling a private constructor:

```
public class UniversityPeople {
    private final Student[] students;
    private final Instructor[] instructors;

    private UniversityPeople(int studentCount, int instructorCount) {
        students = new Student[studentCount];
        instructors = new Instructor[instructorCount];
    }

    public static UniversityPeople forStudents(int size) {
        return new UniversityPeople(size, 0);
    }

    public static UniversityPeople forInstructors(int size) {
        return new UniversityPeople(0, size);
    }
}
```

You could perform a check against each size and only allocate if it's greater than 0 if you really want to. But as I say, I'd revisit the design if possible.

Comment: Yeah, I thought the implementation was weird myself but it's what the instructor has explicitly asked for, so I must obey. To me 2 different classes would make more sense, but I digress. Anyways , this definitely seems like it would work, ty.

Comment: @FuegoJohnson: You might want to put that information in the question. Any time you ask something that you know sounds a little quirky, acknowledge it in the question (and provide the justification) to avoid discussion around that side of things. If this is what you've been asked for, that's fine :)

Comment: very true, I probably should have said something but I was so tired and frustrated w the overall implementation of the class lol. Anyways, thanks for the quick response, I've selected your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need only the direction: look for the design pattern "factory". This should help you.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of this implementation but it seems quite useful, thanks for point me in the right direction.